# Reinstalling package thunderbird does not solve problem with Gnome

Tags: apt, gnome, package-management, thunderbird

I recently installed Gnome on my Dell OptiPlex 755 computer, replacing Ubuntu Unity. The computer (and most applications) now work, for the most part, but I now have a red ball with a white dash in the titlebar, indicating an error. The explanation of the error is:

> An error occurred, please run . . . apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong. The error message was Unknown Error  (E: The package Thunderbird needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.)' This usually means (that) your installed packages have unmet dependencies.

I reinstalled Thunderbird, but received the same response from the terminal.

Why am I still getting the red ball with white dash error indication on my taskbar? My only alternative now seems to be to completely uninstall Gnome and start fresh, but for some reason I can't do that either due to this problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the exact command you ran to reinstall thundrebird and the output it gave you.

Comment: How did you reinstall? Did you try `sudo apt --reinstall install thunderbird`? Unmet dependencies can be repaired with `sudo apt -f install` and `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, please run these commands and [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/947217/edit) your question with the outputs.

Comment: This red icon is from the software updater. There are a number of ways to clear the error, but keep in mind that the red icon doesn't go away immediately after implementing a fix. Usually it's due to "broken" packages... but your error indicates a Thunderbird archive problem. Try uninstalling Thunderbird (don't use completely remove), and reinstalling it, using Synaptic.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

Go here  https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/xenial/main/proposed/thunderbird and download the .deb package for thunderbird 60.9.1
In terminal change to the directory where the .deb file is located.
type sudo dpkg -i --force-all ./thunderbird_60.9.1+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04_amd64.deb
"
(tip: type ls  t   Now hit the tab button.  Now hit return.  Now hit the up arrow.  Now hit the back arrow and replace ls with sudo dpkg -i --force-all ./ ) 
Now type without the quotes: "sudo dpkg --configure -a"
Now open Thunderbird and enter your gmail password and click ok.  It should step through the 2-step authorization successfully.